# Cannot retrieve href for this particular page using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

Following is my code:

```
# -*- coding: ascii -*-

# import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

def gethyperLinks(url):
    html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
    hyperlinks = []

    for link in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'ess-product-desc'}):
        hyperlinks.append(link.get('href'))

    return hyperlinks

print( gethyperLinks("http://biggestbook.com/ui/catalog.html#/search?cr=1&rs=12&st=BM&category=1") )
```

I want to target the following href:

```
<div 
    class="ess-product-desc" ng-hide="currentView == 'detail' `&amp;&amp; deviceType=='mobile'" 
    ui-sref="detail({itemId: 'BWK6400', uom: 'CT', cm_sp:'', merchPreference:''})" 
    href="#/itemDetail?`itemId=BWK6400&amp;uom=CT" aria-hidden="false">
        <span>Center-Pull Hand Towels, 2-Ply, Perforated, 7 7/8 x 10, White, 600/RL, 6 RL/CT</span>
</div>
```

I want to extract that href above but I get `[]` as the final answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the variable `html_page` is the mentioned div available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for the page need javascript to run. That should be clear if you inspect the response (at least with requests). I show an example using selenium so that javascript has time to run. You could convert this to using a function when returning data from a page navigated to during scraping session.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options) 
driver.get("http://biggestbook.com/ui/catalog.html#/search?cr=1&rs=12&st=BM&category=1")
links = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ess-product-brand + [href]")))
results = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]
print(results)
```

There is an API called, with query string parameters, which returns the data in a json format. You have to pass the referrer and a token. If you are able to grab the token, or pass the token in a session (and it remains valid), and can decipher the query string parameters, then that might be the way to go with requests based approach. Not sure about urllib.

https://api.essendant.com/digital/digitalservices/search/v1/search?cr=1&fc=1&listKey=I:D2F9CC81D2919D8712B61A3176A518622A2764B16287CA6576B9CF0C9B5&listKey=I:A81AAA8BD639792D923386B93AC32AC535673530AFBB7A25CAB5AB2E933EAD1&rs=12&st=BM&vc=n

Comment: Whenever I run this using the terminal, it first opens up google chrome. Is there a way to run it without having google chrome open up? Otherwise, your solution works

Comment: run it headless.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. Also, why is it that sometimes more links are given and sometimes few show up? realized that sometimes only the featured are given and sometimes all of them. I am new to this (and coding in general) so do not understand

Comment: I’ll need to do some testing. There was a wait for all elements present but perhaps there is something else that needs to happen. I will have a look tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: did you happen to figure the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I’ll have a look today. Yesterday was crazy busy.

Comment: Hey, do you know good sources for learning this kind of scrapping. I was able to extract other try webs with my code for tables etc

Comment: Did you by any chance get anytime to take a look?

Comment: Also, can you please kindly let me know of good place to study Json website stuff etc so I can get a better understanding and be more independent. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried other ways like this:

links = [elem.get_attribute("href") for elem in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]

print(links)


but it still didn't work. it only gives selected links :S

Comment: Hey man, did you ever get it to work? I still couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,you should use 'html5lib' instead of 'html.parser', like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div 
    class="ess-product-desc" ng-hide="currentView == 'detail' `&amp;&amp; deviceType=='mobile'" 
    ui-sref="detail({itemId: 'BWK6400', uom: 'CT', cm_sp:'', merchPreference:''})" 
    href="#/itemDetail?`itemId=BWK6400&amp;uom=CT" aria-hidden="false">
        <span>Center-Pull Hand Towels, 2-Ply, Perforated, 7 7/8 x 10, White, 600/RL, 6 RL/CT</span>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")
links = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'ess-product-desc'})
links[0].get("href")
```

you will get:

```
'#/itemDetail?`itemId=BWK6400&uom=CT'
```

Comment: thanks but then how would it work by passing 
' print( gethyperLinks("http://biggestbook.com/ui/catalog.html#/search?cr=1&rs=12&st=BM&category=1") ) ' 

since

" <div  class="ess-product-desc" ng-hide="currentView == 'detail' `&amp;&amp; deviceType=='mobile'" 
    ui-sref="detail({itemId: 'BWK6400', uom: 'CT', cm_sp:'', merchPreference:''})" 
    href="#/itemDetail?`itemId=BWK6400&amp;uom=CT" aria-hidden="false">
        <span>Center-Pull Hand Towels, 2-Ply, Perforated, 7 7/8 x 10, White, 600/RL, 6 RL/CT</span>
</div> "


would be different for each item on that page.

Comment: sorry for the poor formatting. still getting used to it. The html you have equated to will be different for each item @Claroja